# NotifyDatasetChanged() to update Listview from server

Tags: c#, android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a ListView whose items are fetched from an Api call. Then I add another item , send it to api to add it. I want to update the existing list with the value I just added.

I am doing something like this:-

```
itemList =   dataAgent.GetItemList(some params);
                 cAdapter = new ItemsListAdapter(this, itemList);
                 lvItems.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                 lvItems.Adapter = cAdapter;
                 SetListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lvItems);

             }
             btnItemComment.Click += btnItemComment_Click;

        void btnItemComment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string itemsText = editComments.Text.ToString().Trim();
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemsText))
            {
                CreateAndShowAlert(this, "", "Please enter a text");

            }
            else
            {
                var status = dataAgent.PostItem (Some more params);
                if(status)
                {
                    cAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

But the ListView does not get refreshed. Is there anything else I need to do? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: add the data to the same list in which you are adding data through api call

Answer (score 0):

Set adapter again and then add NotifyDataSetChanged:-

cAdapter = new ItemsListAdapter(this, itemList);

cAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();